# Trigger.oldMap.get on a boolean field

Tags: trigger, boolean

This may be trivial, but I am confused.

I am trying to do a field change comparison in a trigger (trigger.oldMap vs trigger.newMap) on a boolean custom field I have in cases. This causes an incorrect signature error, when I do the exact same thing on other filed types like text areas or picklist it work fine.

Is there a reason I can't do it on a boolean, and if so is there a workaround for it, I have tried with trigger.old.get(theField) but that gave the same error?

```
        case oldStatus = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Status);                      //picklist field type
        case oldClosedBy = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Case_Closed_by_User__c);    //boolean field type. give error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Boolean) from the type Map<Id,Case>"
        case oldQueue = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Case_Queue_Name__c);           //text area field type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger.old is Map of Case Id and Case instance.

To retrieve the field values, you will need to specify the ID as index and then the field name to get the corresponding values.

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(Case_ID).FieldName
```

> Trigger.oldMap - A map of IDs to the old versions of the sObject
> records.
>
> Trigger.newMap - A map of IDs to the new versions of the sObject
> records.
>
> Trigger.old - A list of the old versions of the sObject
> records.
>
> Trigger.new - A list of the new versions of the sObject
> records.

You may use Trigger.new, which is a list of Cases

```
for(Case newCase: Trigger.new){  //iterate through the list
    //Get field values you need
    System.debug('** Picklist : Case Status : ' + newCase.Status);
    System.debug('** Boolean : Case Closed by User : ' + newCase.Case_Closed_by_User__c);
    System.debug('** Text : Case Queue Name : ' + newCase.Case_Queue_Name__c);

    //For the comparison, do:
    //get old Case
    Case oldCase = Trigger.OldMap.get(newCase.Id);

   //Compare old and new value
   if(oldCase.Case_Closed_by_User__c != newCase.Case_Closed_by_User__c){
       //your logic here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that cleared my trivial question.

Answer (score 4):

Those maps are keyed by record Ids. So when looking for differences between the values of of the fields in the old and new records use this pattern:

```
// n = new version of record
// o = old version of record
for (Case n : Trigger.new) {
    Case o = Trigger.oldMap.get(n.Id);

    if (n.Case_Closed_by_User__c != o.Case_Closed_by_User__c) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Worth spending a few minutes reading about the details of what is available from the [Trigger Context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm?search_text=trigger%20context).